# Haskell list iteration

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a list `[a,b,c,d,e]` and an initial value `u` (obviously `a,b,c,d,e` represent values). I want to apply a function to `e` and `u`, let's say `f(e,u)`. I then want to apply the function `f(d, f(e, u))` and then `f(c, f(d, f(e, u)))` etc. I have looked at "iterate", but I cannot work out how to apply iterate to each element in a list.

My list:

```
a = take 101 (0 : concat [[(1%1),(2*k%1),(1%1)] | k <- [1..40]])
```

How would I go about implementing this in Haskell?

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? I think `map` or `fold` might help here...

Comment: I will sit down tomorrow night and attempt to clarify my question for future readers. Unfortunately I had trouble wording it when I wrote it.

Comment: Computing *e* are we? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you describe is called a "[fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29)", in this case a "right fold" because it is applied from right to left. It is implemented in the Prelude as the [`foldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afoldr) function.

For instance, if we take the function `(++)` that concatenates two strings, and apply it to an initial element and list of strings:

```
Prelude> foldr (++) "u" ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
"abcdeu"
```

Comment: `foldr` doesn't work from right to left, it's *r*ight-associative fold

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Haskell's functionality continues to amaze me.

Answer (score 6):

You want `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`. Which is the general fold of the list data structure. Think of it as replacing all the `(:)` and `[]` constructors in the list by the two supplied arguments.

For example, if we were to sum the numbers of the list `[1, 2, 3]`, constructed as `1 : (2 : (3 : []))`, we could find a *replacement* of the `(:)` and `[]`, like `+` and `0`, i.e. `1 + (2 + (3 + 0))`. We could thus implement `sum :: Num a => [a] -> a` as `foldr (+) 0`.

Answer (score 3):

Good job, you've discovered `foldr` on your own!  (I hope that doesn't sound mocking or anything, it's not meant that way; most people find folds unnatural and have to think really hard to understand it!)

The way I would suggest you handle these situations is to try writing the function you want on your own, and figuring out the type, and then searching for that type in [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to see if there already exists such a function.

In this case, you could try writing your function this way.  We'll call it `foo`:

```
-- If we see an empty list the result should be u
foo u f [] = u
-- If we're given a a non-empty list we recurse down the list to get a partial 
-- result, then "add on" to it:
foo u f (x:xs) = f x (foo u f xs)
```

Once you define this function, you can load it into `ghci` and use its `:t` command to find its type:

```
*Main> :load "../src/scratch.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ../src/scratch.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> :t foo
foo :: t1 -> (t -> t1 -> t1) -> [t] -> t1
```

Now we can [search Hoogle for the type `t1 -> (t -> t1 -> t1) -> [t] -> t1`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=t1+-%3E+%28t+-%3E+t1+-%3E+t1%29+-%3E+%5Bt%5D+-%3E+t1).  The top result is `foldr`, which has the type `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`—the same as `foo` but with the variables renamed and the argument order flipped.  The search result also tells us that the function is in the `Prelude` module—the module that's loaded by default by Haskell.  You can click on the result to find [its definition in the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afoldr), which describes it with this equation:

```
foldr f z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == x1 `f` (x2 `f` ... (xn `f` z)...)
```

They're using the `f` function as an infix operator, which I hope doesn't confuse you, but just in case we can rewrite this to:

```
foldr f z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == f x1 (f x2 ... (f xn z) ...)
```

Which is exactly the behavior you want.

---

Why did I make such a big deal out of `foldr` above?  Because `foldr` is actually the most fundamental function for taking lists apart.  Look at the type this way:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b)  -- ^ What to do with a list node
      -> b              -- ^ What to do with the empty list
      -> [a]            -- ^ A list
      -> b              -- ^ The final result of "taking the list apart."
```

It turns out that a lot of list functions can be written easily in terms of `foldr`:

```
map f = foldr step []
    where step x rest = (f x):rest

-- | Append two lists
xs (++) ys = foldr (:) ys xs

-- | Filter a list, keeping only elements that satisfy the predicate.
filter pred = foldr step []
    where step x rest | pred x    = x:rest
                      | otherwise = rest

-- | Find the first element of a list that satisfies the predicate.
find pred = foldr step Nothing
    where step x r | pred x    = Just x
                   | otherwise = r
```

Answer (score 2):

Right fold looks good.

```
foo :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foo f u xs = foldr (\x acc -> f x acc) u xs
```

I find that when learning a language one often can have the question "Is there an easier way to do this?" The answer is almost always yes.

Comment: `\x acc -> f x acc` is the same as simply `f`.   (I can understand why you would expand for demonstrative purposes, though)

Comment: The same reason I put in xs :)